Привязка WPF UserControl: свойство не найдено в DataContext при использовании в ListBox ItemTemplate
Я столкнулся с проблемой привязки данных в WPF. Я использую ListBox, в котором каждый элемент представляет собой UserControl. Однако при попытке привязать свойства к UserControl, я получаю следующую ошибку:

"Property 'Document' not found on object of type 'MainViewModel'."

Привязка осуществляется через ItemsSource, который указывает на коллекцию объектов типа Records. Внутри RecordsPanel (UserControl) я пытаюсь привязать свойства типа Document, NumberOrder и т.д., но они не видны. Как я могу правильно передать контекст данных в UserControl и исправить эту проблему?
Вот мой код:
XAML:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListRecords}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:RecordsPanel TextDocument="{Binding Document}"
                            TextNumberOrder="{Binding NumberOrder}"
                            TextCount="{Binding Count}"
                            TextDate="{Binding Date}"
                            TextComment="{Binding Comment}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>

UserControl (RecordsPanel):
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.RecordsPanel"
         ...>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextDocument}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextNumberOrder}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextCount}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextDate}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextComment}" />
</Grid>

UserControl (RecordsPanel.xaml.cs):
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDocumentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextDocument", typeof(string), typeof(RecordsPanel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string TextDocument
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextDocumentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextDocumentProperty, value); }
    }

Класс Records:
public class Records
{
    public string Document { get; set; }
    public string NumberOrder { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

Я использую PropertyChanged.Fody для автоматического уведомления об изменениях свойств. Подскажите, как правильно настроить привязку данных внутри UserControl?

TextDocument - это что? Как реализованы эти свойства? P.S. Fody - не лучший вариант, который означает, что вы используете древний .NET Framework.

Я добавил информацию. Учился по роликам 6 летней давности. А сейчас использую 8.0

Так, а почему привязка тогда у вас обычная? В контролах привязываться надо на самого себя, через имя например. Другими словами, не {Binding TextDocument} а <UserControl x:Name="uc">... {Binding TextDocument, ElementName=uc}. Также не забывайте, что данные о коде обновляются зачастую только после успешной сборки проекта.

Сделал как вы сказали, но текста все так же нет. Сборка выполняется без ошибок, но если смотреть в отладке, то ошибка привязки показывается такая же. Если я использую вместо UserControl обычный textbox, то текст передается правильно.

Делайте тогда минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который можно будет скопировать и вставить в чистый проект.

@EvgeniyZ Чего это Fody означает? Прекрасно работает на всех версиях core вплоть до текущей 8й.

Они не видны потому что внутри юзерконтрола Binding TextDocument ищет эти свойства в DataContext, который в данный момент есть Records (кстати для Fody нужно INPC реализовать). Вам нужно указать что искать TextDocument нужно в самом контроле, как то через RelativeSource Self или, что проще, ElementName="Root" (не забыв присвоить Name="Root" юзерконтролу)

@vitidev Держите в курсе, ваше мнение важно. Ну а если серьезно, то он бесполезен на современном .NET от словам совсем. Раньше данную библиотеку использовали для того, чтоб собрать все в один .exe, сейчас это делает сам .NET. Далее, INPC, раньше эта библиотека такими костылями реализовывала все это, потом появилась генерация кода и весь функционал фоди стал бесполезным, после чего автор пошел в генерацию, а после чего Microsoft выпустили CommunityToolkit, который по сей день развивается, а фоди застыл в 22 году. Так что, по моему опыту, фоди используют обычно в старых проектах, не более.

@EvgeniyZ как и ваше. То, что выпустили CommunityToolkit - не значит что все прямо забыли про все остальное и стали использовать только его. Мантра "это же от майков" не всех заставляет бросать удобный тулинг ради нового (причем не самого удобного). А новички другого и не видели. И мое мнение иное. Fody - лучший вариант по сравнению с решением от майков. Сам он живее всех живых, а его аддон PropertyChanged вполне жив судя по репе. Ну не обновлялся давно - ну значит автор не видит что еще туда можно добавить ибо свою работу аддон делает. А обновление ради обновлений...

Я создал новый проект и использовал там CommunityToolkit, вроде работает. Я так же попытался основной проект перенести на CommunityToolkit, но там все так же не работает. В основном проекте я еще мало чего реализовал, так что попробую заново начать писать. Вот ссылка на основной проект: https://github.com/artemmovish/KeepRecordsFluentWPF

@vitidev Ну так пользуйтесь, кто я такой, чтоб запрещать вам. Вы спросили почему - я вам ответил, почему считаю, что у человека старый .NET Framework. Ну опыт у меня такой, ну статистика моя говорит, прям кричит, что в 90% случаев, Fody сразу означает старый .NET Framework, что поделать... На этом все, закончили спор? Или перейдем в дебри функционала, что лучше, а что нет? Заметьте, я не говорил, что какая либо библиотека лучше, я лишь указал на то, что INPC компонент с 22 года не обновлялся, а это, как по мне, очень весомый аргумент задуматься. Так что, прекращайте цепляться к чужим словам.

@ArtemmovishArtemmovish <UserControl.DataContext> уберите из контрола. Контролы не должны ничего знать про данные, они должны только отображать те свойства, которые имеют у себя, не более. Вообще установка DataContext не должно быть где либо, кроме главного окна. Также, DataContext не должен устанавливаться в XAML, это, по сути, является нарушением MVVM, ибо окно (View) знает про VM слой, да и не только знает, но и руководит им, отвечает за его срок жизни (подробно о том, почему плохо и как лучше, написано тут).

Теперь выходит я не знаю что именно помогло решить проблему, часть с DataContext я добавил в отчайных попытках все исправить. Спасибо за помощь, теперь все работает.

По этой причине я и говорил, делайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример, в котором будет голый WPF  проект без библиотек лишних (INPC в вашем случае вообще не нужен), в котором будет только нужный функционал, показывающий наглядно проблему. Кстати, FluentWPF вы тоже зря поставили, это очень древняя библиотека, которая очень сильно нагружает приложение (у меня окно вашего приложения с дикими задержками двигается). Ну и +, в современном WPF она бесполезна, ибо Mica и прочие эффекты были добавлены в сам WPF (правда начиная с .NET9). Так что, советую подумать на этот счет)

а как я могу установить .net9, в visual studio installer я нашел только до 8.0?

На данный момент он в превью (нужна превью студия). В ноябре должен выйти. Как подцепить современный стиль, рассказано тут (достаточно указать .NET9 и прописать в App.xaml соответствующие стили).
